Degeneracy of Orbitals
(Sorry, in advance if my question is silly or low quality but I want to ask this to someone.)
When an electron enters an orbital, it should technically have an electric Field and also magnetic field(Moving charge), so shouldn't orbitals once partially or fully filled lose degeneracy?
Also, why are different spin states seen(High Spin/Low Spin) in only d-block elements like Fe?
If all the orbitals were not degenrate, then what would happen exactly?

Two orbitals are degenerate when they have the same energy, whatever their spin or other properties.

Important note: it's a common misconception to separate orbitals and electrons. The orbitals ARE the electrons. If the energy of two orbitals (electron) are the same, they are defined as degenerate. This can be related to the symmetry of the system (which is fully defined within the full Hamiltonian), system with high symmetry (such as atoms) have "a lot of" degeneracy whereas system with low symmetry (such as big non-symmetric molecules) have "low" degeneracy.

I would not think about the properties of orbitals changing if you place the electrons in them. Let's first reitterate the proces of finding he orbitals. You first have the Hamiltonian where all the effects of the electrons are included (this is your system). Then when you calculate eigenvalues (energies) and eigenequations (orbitals) by diagonalizing your Hamiltonian you found the orbitals and corresponding energies. The "filling" of the orbitals with electrons does not change anything anymore as your system does not change by this filling.
Comming back to your degeneracy question. If your calculated eigenenergies of some orbitals are the same they are degenerate. Then again, the energy of these orbitals will not be altered by containing zero, one, or two electrons. The crux lies in the Hamiltonian, this specifies all your interactions between electrons and nuclei etc. so when you solve the Schrödinger equation your energy levels are fixed. I must note that there are cases where you will have changes in energy levels due to excitations (excitonic binding energy) or external fields (fine splitting).
I am not an inorganic chemist so I should not attempt answering your second question about d-metal complexes. But maybe this page could be helpfull: https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Douglas_College/DC%3A_Chem_2330_(O'Connor)/4%3A_Crystal_Field_Theory/4.3%3A_High_Spin_and_Low_Spin_Complexes.
Lastly, when all orbitals are non-degenerate (which if you look very closely until hyperfine splitting etc. will nearly always be the case) nothing special happens. To find the electron configuration in the orbitals you will have to fill up the orbitals from the bottom up as usual and there just won't be orbitals that have the same energy.
